# How to Change label text from loaded fxml

Tags: javafx, fxml

```
public class ProjectxController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane LandingPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    } 

    @FXML
    private void onLoad(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

           pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("connectedPage.fxml")); 
           LandingPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);


    }
```

Note: Having two fxml files `Frontpage.fxml` and `ConnectedPage.fxml` with one controller `projectxController` i.e coded above

1. `Frontpage.fxml` has one button that will load `connectedPage.fxml`.
2. `Connectedpage.fxml` has one label

Now I want to set the  Label text after `connectedpage.fxml` is loaded

```
public class ProjectX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FrontPage.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Comment: I tried with label.setText("ABC"); but this is giving exception

Comment: Exception are launched to be fixed ^^ so can you give us the details of it ?

Comment: Don't use the same controller class for the controllers from two different FXML files. It is too difficult to keep track of what is initialized in each instance of the controller. Use a different controller class for each FXML file.

Answer (score 0):

When you create you fxml document you have to give a unique id for you Label:

The same you have done for the AnchorPane.

Example

```
@FXML
private Label myLabel;
```

Then inside the initialize method of your fxml controller class you can modify it as you want.

If you problem is how to access the Label from another controller you can use a get method or pass an instance of the controller you need . All that after the fxml has successfully loaded .

I recommend also that you use different controllers for different fxml files , cause it is more clear .

Have a search on `fxml loading techniques and how to connect different controllers` over the web and you will find what you need .